# How do I make sure that OS X Mavericks is successfully installed?

Tags: macos

How do I know if OS X Mavericks was installed successfully? In the App Store, will the button next to the OS X Mavericks app be shown as "Installed" after the completion of installation?

Comment: Do you mean the App Store status? Or... where?

Comment: yes! I mean the App Store status...will it be shown as installed? cos mine still shown as download.

Answer (score 3):

Click the  in the top left of your screen and select "About This Mac". If it says "Version 10.9.x" then you have successfully upgraded to Mavericks!

[image]

The installer app should have removed itself, but if it didn't you can go ahead and delete it manually.

And in the App Store it should show you a "Download" button instead of a greyed out "Installed" button. This is so you can download it again to reinstall OS X or install on another Mac. The App Store is not the place to check what version of OS X is installed, only to *download* apps and new versions of OS X.

Comment: Besides that, what about the app store status?

Comment: @skycloud92 See edit.